# Decrease polling interval for web3.myContract.myEvent()

Tags: events

The following seems to poll my Ethereum node every second:

```
web3.eth.contract(contractAbi).at(contractAddress).allEvents(callback);
```

Is there a way to decrease the polling interval?

Comment: why dont you use watch or subscribe via websocket then you dont need to poll anymore?

Comment: There is not. :(

Answer (score 2):

Indeed you need to use `WebsocketProvider`, it gives you opportunity to receive notification instantly after node synchronization.

```
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws'));

var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(<abi>, <address>);
myContract.events.allEvents({ fromBlock: 'latest' }, console.log);
```